# R Shiny: Conditional panel based on row selected in datatable

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to Shiny. I want to get a new panel based on the row I have selected in datatable. So far I have added the following code but it does not seem to work. What condition do you have to put so that the new panel is shown and previous get removed?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

conditionalPanel(
condition <- "is. null(input.dt_rows_selected) == TRUE",
DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "dt")
),
  conditionalPanel(
condition <- "is. null(input.dt_rows_selected) == FALSE" ,
h3("Plots based on the selected row ")
)
)


server <- function(input, output){

output$dt <- DT::renderDataTable(
mtcars, server = FALSE, selection = 'single'
)
}


shinyApp(ui =ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check two option :

1) input exists

2) input >0

like :

```
conditionalPanel(
    condition ="typeof input.dt_rows_selected  === 'undefined' || input.dt_rows_selected.length <= 0",
    DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "dt"))
  ,
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "typeof input.dt_rows_selected  !== 'undefined' && input.dt_rows_selected.length > 0" ,
    h3("Plots based on the selected row ")
  )
```

After select row DT hidden and text showed

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its exactly what I wanted :)